# How to check if player is facing cube node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, 3d, server, direction

I'm making the server for a 3d space game and am currently working on combat. the basic idea is like an fps, i.e. if the spaceship is facing another spaceship and he shoots and the distances between the ships is small enough, it's a hit. i've decided to represent each ships hit box as just a cube of 20x10 units. so my question is.

I have a player and his direction is (dX, dY, dZ) and position is (x,y,z) and i have a cube who's position is (x1, y1, z1). How can i tell if the player is facing the cube?

Comment: That's actually a Maths problem. Google something like "angle between vectors".

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a math question but could be simply solved seeing if a vector is on the same direction of another one:

1) First create the vector of the player with the cube by CubePos-PlayerPos, this will give you a  vector

2)Check if the vectors have [the same direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646780/how-to-tell-if-two-3d-vectors-are-in-the-same-direction) (they should be proportional)

Comment: Thanks :) I've been putting off learning game dev maths for a while ... I guess it's time